# Upload a file with empty content

Tags: python, django

This is my templates:

```
<p>Upload</p>
<form action="{% url upload_url %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ upload_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

This is my form:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a file',
        help_text='you can upload file'
    )
```

This is my code:

```
form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    # do something
```

When I upload a file with empty content, I try to check reason of errors. I get this:

```
# form.is_valid()
False
# form.errors
<ul class="errorlist"><li>docfile<ul class="errorlist"><li>The subm
itted file is empty.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

I am sure that I have uploaded a file, but it's just empty content of file. What's happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is default behavior of [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#filefield) if you want to allow empty file just set `allow_empty_file=True`:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a file',
        help_text='you can upload file',
        allow_empty_file=True
    )
```

Comment: It's right. I look "Has two optional arguments for validation, max_length and allow_empty_file." with paragraph. It's helpful for me. Thanks.